# What does Tom mean when he said “If you're a man, then do it with a 'Don'”?

Tags: one-piece

In episode 313 of *One Piece*, there was a scene referencing Tom said in the past,

[image: a screenshot]

> If you are a man, then do with a "Don".

What does this mean?

Comment: Just off-hand speculation, since I don't know Japanese (or Japanese onomatopoeias), or if this is a real saying, but I think "Don" here might be an onomatopoeia, a similar english word being something like "bang". So I think he's saying something like "Do it with a bang", or to do something in a way that is very impactful,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spanish "don" means "to be gifted" as in special talent. Also, don is sometimes informally used to refer to mafia/gangster-like behaviour or actions, which might be used to refer to pirates as well.

Knowing how Oda-sensei loves Spanish influence, to my understanding, the meaning is: If you're a man do it as a talented person would (do your best).

Answer (score 4):

I found an alternative translation of the anime:

[image]

> If you're a man, do it resolutely.

I also looked into the printed volume I own and there stands (translated in English):

> If you're a man, do it with ambition.

Those two translations are quite consistent so I'm not quite sure if Ivan's answer is actually correct.

Beside that, the manga translation I found the most online is also the one given given in the OP:

[image]

But I also found the translation suggested in St. Pat's comment:

[image]

> If you're a man, do it with a bang.

Answer (score 2):

don is like saying meow, it is a sound representing a drum = do it with a bang with gusto with spirit, whole-hearted.

source: https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/4kyfn2/what_is_don/